# i' m using Bootstrap Timepicker with twitter bootstrap but it doesn't shows the timepicker popup on clicking the timeicon

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

when I clicked on time icon it shows nothing. I am using this code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Next Time</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the script and CSS i m using:

```
<link type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Is any error is shown on your browser console ?

Comment: Seems to work fine here

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the id on your parent div :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Next Time</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="timepicker1" class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input type="text" class="input-small">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks guys it was my fault as there was Js file missing.thnks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.
Have you include jquery and bootstrap scripts, css too?